# Email Using Javascript or Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

I am using ajax to send email. When I take the value of message box, it will not take the line breaks. How to take the contents without losing its alignments using JavaScript. Jquery shows some problem so I am using pure JavaScript and ajax functionality. Please help me.

Comment: Ajax does not send mail - it makes HTTP requests. Please describe your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u using php as an backend script?

If so: try [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function.

If not, try to post your code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to HTML escape the newline character: %0A

<a href="mailto:mike@mike.com?subject=New lines!&body=A new line will go%0Ahere">Email me</a>